# PMD command running multiple rules at once from Shell

Tags: java, shell, unix, rules, pmd

I'm trying out PMD on some Java source code.
I understand from the Terminal window on my Mac (Unix shell), the syntax is like so:
**pmd.sh  html|xml|text|vbhtml rulesetfile1[,rulesetfile2[,..]]**
But the question is, what are the names rulesetfile1, 2 ... n...
I mean I've seen this list on the website:
http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/index.html
But how does this correlate to the comma separated list I can supply from running the shell command?
Can someone point me to a cross-reference so I can correlate the two?
Cheers.

Comment: Please don't forget to go back and mark answers to some of your questions as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This should be available in the `ruleset` folder of pmd installation.  [Here](https://pmd.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/pmd/trunk/pmd/rulesets/java/) is the link to the folder in PMD's source repository.

Comment: When I looked at that, it had one called 'empty' that I couldn't get to work - I took 4.2.5 build admittedly. I couldn't see a ruleset folder, but did come across a 'rules' folder and have been using the names of those html files without the html suffix. That has been yielding some interesting results. Have to say I like PMD..